# How to iterate over alternative elements using an iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

The above code will iterate sequentially 1 through 6. Can we iterate the same list alternatively so that it will print `1, 3, 5` without changing the while loop?

Comment: One possibility would be to rearrange your list, or to check the values before printing it (`if (x==1 || x==3 || x==6)`). (It doesn't answer your question, which seems not possible)

Comment: Just wondering: why are you asking? What real problem do you want to solve here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create your own `Iterator`.

```
class SkippingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    private currentPosition;
    private int skipBy;
    public SkippingIterator(List<T> l) {
        this(l, 2);
    }
    public SkippingIterator(List<T> l, int skip) {
        this(l, skipBy, 0);
    }
    public SkippingIterator(List<T> l, int skip, int startPosition) {
        list = l;
        skipBy = skip;
        currentPosition = startPosition;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return currentPosition < list.size();
    }
    public T next() {
        T result = list.get(currentPosition);
        currentPosition += skip;
        return result;
    }
}
```

making your code

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Iterator it = new SkippingIterator<>(list);
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the hasNext method also make use of the skipyBy attribute as in `(currentPosition + skipBy) <= list.size()`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS well the `currentPosition` points at the next item that will be output, so that's what needs to be valid. Now that you mention it though, maybe it makes sense to add a `startPosition` so you can skip at the beginning as well.

Comment: Oh, okay. Never mind then. I somehow thought it was pointing to the last item that was output.

Comment: @daniu Thanks Daniu...perfect solution for  that I was needed.

Comment: @daniu very good, but I think this is easier to implement in java-8, since there is a single `tryAdvance` method IMO... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331960/1059372, I still upvoted

Answer (score 7):

You only want to print the odd numbers? Filter the list with a stream:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Iterator<Integer> it = list.stream().filter(x -> x % 2 == 1).iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Edit:

if you want to get every other element then using streams will be less appropriate, but you can still do it:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
int limit = list.size() / 2 - (1 - list.size() % 2);
Iterator<Integer> it = IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 2).limit(limit).map(list::get).iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

I recommend daniu's solution.

Comment: I wasn't even aware `Stream` has an `iterator()` method... neat.

Comment: I want to print alternative element not odd number. Will your code print alternative element if the list will List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40,50,61);

Comment: @Sweeper I really wanted to post close to the same thing (your second approach), but I think this is a job for a custom spliterator... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331960/1059372 still 1+

Answer (score 7):

A simple mechanism is to just use the index of the list items:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .mapToObj(list::get)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

And if you particularly want an iterator, just call `iterator()` instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. Inside the while loop's body, check if the iterator has a next element, and if it does, advance the iterator again. This will cause the even elements not to be printed.

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Iterator it=list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's changing the while-loop.

Comment: @daniu I assumed the OP meant without changing the while loop's condition. Perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: It's weird to me. Since the `Iterator` is an interface, more appropriate way to achieve OP's quest is overriding the `Iterator` methods.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the java-8 way to do it would be something like this:

```
class Skipping extends AbstractSpliterator<Integer> {

    private List<Integer> list;
    private int index = 0;

    public Skipping(List<Integer> list) {
        super(list.size() / 2, 0);
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        if (index != list.size()) {
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                action.accept(list.get(index++));
            }
            ++index;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And usage:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
Iterator<Integer> iter = StreamSupport.stream(new Skipping(list), false).iterator();
```

Comment: An elegant solution, except for the deletion part, as for bigger collections this can become quite expensive. Maybe rather use an incrementing counter as the index

Comment: @Lino I am still thinking about it... and yes, I totally agree with you. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

You could create an Iterator implementation that wraps an already existant iterator:

```
class IteratorWrapper<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Iterator<? extends T> iterator;

    public IteratorWrapper(Iterator<? extends T> iterator){
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    public T next(){
        final T next = iterator.next();
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator.next();
        }
        return next;
    }

    public void remove(){
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

making your code the following:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Iterator<Iterator> it = new IteratorWrapper<>(list.iterator());
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: This looks like the decorator pattern. Why don't we override an `Iterator` methods instead?

Comment: Well you might not always know the source of an Iterator and thus can not directly override an existing one. E.g. an iterator from an `ArrayList` may differ than that from a `HashSet`

Comment: Yep, **but** for some concrete classes and concrete implementations we're able to know (in advance) what and how we can implement the `Iterator` interface. E.g. `IteratorForDivisibleBySeven`

Comment: @zlakad of course, but my approach is the most generic one, of course you might want to override an existing `Iterator` if you know that you use exactly that functionallity

Comment: I agree, the decorator pattern could be used in the more generic cases... Still, if you want to use more than one iterator over the Collection you can use a multiply implementations of `Iterator`. Even more, you could use a strategy pattern.

Comment: @Randhir, if you found this answer is the most useful for you, then you should at least accept this answer and give it +1 vote.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator` implementation that wraps an already existing iterator. It provides the logically correct definition of `hasNext()` method for alternate iterator as the `hasNext()` method should return true only if the alternate position number is present.

```
    import java.util.Iterator;

    public class AlternateIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{

        private T next;
        private Iterator<T> it;

        public AlternateIterator(Iterator<T> it) {
            this.it = it;
            next = null;
        }
        // Logically hasNext() of this iterator should return true only if it has a valid alternate element present.
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(next != null) {
                return true;
            }
            if(it.hasNext()) {
                it.next();
                if(it.hasNext()) {
                    next = it.next();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(next != null) {
                T temp = next;
                next = null;
                return temp;
            }
            else {
                if(hasNext())
                    return next();
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom iterator from any underlying iterator:

```
class TwoStepsAtOnceIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private Iterator<E> internal;
    public TwoStepsAtOnceIterator(Iterator<E> it) {
      internal = it;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return internal.hasNext();
    }
    public E next() {
      // problem not specified when underlying sequence has odd number of elements
      internal.next();
      return internal.next();
    }
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will throw an exception in `next()` if the internal iterator has an odd number of items.

Comment: @daniu certainly but it is unspecified which behaviour should be implemented in that case, so I decided to let it throws its "natural" exception

Comment: you might want to delegate the remove method to the underlying iterator. Or at least throw an exception

Comment: you don't have to remove anything, just delegate the `remove()`-method to the `internal`-Iterator, or, as you've now done, throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thats right, as the behaviour is not realy defined (should the first or second element be deleted?)

Answer (score -1):

A very simple code goes like this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Iterator it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
   static int i=0;
    if(i%2==0){
    System.out.println(it.next());
     }
     i+=1;
}
```